# User details not getting updated in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web, backend

I am trying to get the functionality of user updating his profile while being logged in.But when i try to update the fields,for example the "name" field,it doesn't get updated although it runs without any error.It remains the same even after running properly.
Here is my code.

```
const filterObj = (obj, ...allowedFields) => {
  const newObj = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((el) => {
    if (allowedFields.includes(el)) newObj[el] = obj[el];
  });
  return newObj;
};

exports.updateMe = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.password || req.body.passwordConfirm) {
    return next(new AppError('This route is not for password updates.', 400));
  }
  //Filtering out field names that are not allowed to be updated
  const filteredBody = filterObj(req.body, 'name', 'email');
  //Updating the user data
  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, filteredBody, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  });
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      user: updatedUser,
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.user.id}, {filteredBody}, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  }); 
did you try like this ?

Comment: I just tried like this but it doesn't get any better.The output is still the same.